# Holoviews/Bokeh Area Plot Add Hovertool to Area Plot

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I'd like to add a hovertool to my holoviews area plot such that the user can hover over a an x/y coordinate (x and y are discreet) and the hover tool will snap to the nearest x/y coordinate by category. I've set my opts to have the tools set to hover, but I'm not seeing any info other than the cross hover. Anything I can do with this tutorial code below to replicate that functionality?

Here is the link to the tutorial code as well: http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/matplotlib/area_chart.html

```html
%%output size=200
%%opts Area  [height=200 width=400 tools=['hover'] xrotation=90] 
%%opts Overlay [width=600 legend_position='top_left' tools=['hover']] 

# create some example data
python=np.array([2, 3, 7, 5, 26, 221, 44, 233, 254, 265, 266, 267, 120, 111])
pypy=np.array([12, 33, 47, 15, 126, 121, 144, 233, 254, 225, 226, 267, 110, 130])
jython=np.array([22, 43, 10, 25, 26, 101, 114, 203, 194, 215, 201, 227, 139, 160])

dims = dict(kdims='time', vdims='memory')
python = hv.Area(python, label='python', **dims)
pypy   = hv.Area(pypy,   label='pypy',   **dims)
jython = hv.Area(jython, label='jython', **dims)

overlay = (python * pypy * jython).options('Area', fill_alpha=0.5)
overlay.relabel("Area Chart") + hv.Area.stack(overlay).relabel("Stacked Area Chart")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly import

`from bokeh.models import HoverTool`

define your figure

`from bokeh.plotting import figure`

`fig = figure(some settings)`

and add Hovertool to figure

`ht = HoverTool(show_arrow=False, tooltips=[if any], ..some settings)`

`fig.add_tools(ht)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to place nicely with Holoviews. If you can make it work with the code above, can you please write your solution?